# Default user parameters in PyCharm

Tags: sql, pycharm

I love that I can [parameterize SQL queries in Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2019.2/settings-tools-database-user-parameters.html). I an write a statement like so

```sql
select * from table where date >= ?
```

and will then be prompted for the value to be filled in for the `?`.

Alas, I will be prompted afresh every time. Is there a way of specifying a set of default parameters? Bonus points for being able to pull these parameter values from a JSON/yaml file.

Comment: is ok for you set this default parameters using a SQL command or is it mandatory to have a PyCharm feature ?

Comment: I know how to do this in SQL. I would love to have these come from PyCharm.